# Insert value into subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert the value '1' into column 'isTransfer' of every result of an subquery, but it's not working. This is the query where I select the rows:

```
select r.* 
from players r 
inner join ( 
   select name, rating, max(id) id 
   from players group by name, rating 
   having count(distinct club) > 1 
   ) 
q on r.name = q.name and r.rating = q.rating and r.id = q.id
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO 'isTransfer' VALUES '1' WHERE
(select r.* 
    from players r 
    inner join ( 
       select name, rating, max(id) id 
       from players group by name, rating 
       having count(distinct club) > 1 
       ) 
    q on r.name = q.name and r.rating = q.rating and r.id = q.id)
```

Comment: I think you're looking for `UPDATE` not `INSERT`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this task, you need to do an `UPDATE` query. Also, you cannot use the `WHERE` clause like that, you will get an error. Instead, change the where clause to look where the primary key is returned by the subquery. It would look something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET isTransfer = 1
WHERE primaryKey IN [mySubquery];
```

You need to make sure that the only column in your `SELECT` of the subquery is the primary key, otherwise you will get an invalid operand count error.

---

In regards to your query in the comments, the `JOIN` is not necessary. Instead, just get the distinct `id` values from the subquery like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id
FROM(
   SELECT name, rating, MAX(id) AS id
   FROM players
   GROUP BY name, rating
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT club) > 1) q
```

Then, but that query as your `IN` operand.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply! I tried this: `UPDATE players SET isTransfer = 1 WHERE id IN (select r.id from players r inner join ( select name, rating, max(id) id from players group by name, rating having count(distinct club) > 1 ) q on r.name = q.name and r.rating = q.rating and r.id = q.id)` But it says: `#1093 - You can't specify target table 'players' for update in FROM clause `

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the id is unique in the players table:

```
update players r inner join
       (select name, rating, max(id) as id 
        from players p
        group by name, rating 
        having count(distinct club) > 1 
       ) nr
       on r.id = nr.id
    set isTransfer = 1;
```